# How to slice x chars from date?

Tags: javascript

I use `Date.now()` to get the current timestamp in unix format.
I try to cut the last x chars from the timestamp. I tried it with `currentTime = currentTime.slice(0, -4);` but i get `Uncaught TypeError: currenTime.slice is not a function`

```js
currentTime = Date.now();
document.getElementById("out1").innerHTML = "out1 = " + currentTime;

currentTime = currentTime.slice(0, -4);
document.getElementById("out2").innerHTML = "out2 = " + currentTime;
```

```html
<p id="out1">out1 = </p>
<p id="out2">out2 = </p>
```

Comment: Try this,currentTime = Date.now().slice(0, -4); i am not sure,as i have not tested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could convert the date to string:

```
Date.now().toString().slice(0, -4)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no such function called `slice` available with `number`.

you can use simple math at this context,

```
currentTime = (currentTime/10000) | 0;
//The above code will cut off last four digit from the number i.e]currentTime
```

Comment: Why are you using the pipe symbol `| 0` what is the purpose?

Comment: Basically `|` or operation will happen over 32 bit integers. So after dividing the number with 10000 it may return a decimal, in order to truncate the decimal points I have used it.

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy : Thanks for sharing this.